# Firestore Security Rules for collection within a document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to secure my data in Firestore. I have read the documentation and managed to arrange rules for the better part of my db but I struggle with one certain case:

the structure of the data is like this:

collection("connections").document( Uid1 ).collection( Uid2 ).().()

I want to allow access to this whole tree for Uid1 and Uid2. What would be the rule for this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. I was already using the wildcard syntax before but in this particular case I struggled implementing it together with the "userId" wildcard. But I could figure it out now. Heres my working solution if anyone wants to implement similar structure:

```
    match /connections/{userId}/{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /connections/{otheruser}/{userId}/{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the recursive wildcard syntax, `{name=**}`, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=1#recursive_wildcards).

> ```
> service cloud.firestore {   
>     match /databases/{database}/documents {
>      // Matches any document in the cities collection as well as any document in a subcollection.
>         match /cities/{document=**} {
>            allow read, write: if <condition>;
>         }   
>      } 
> }
> ```
>
> When using the recursive wildcard syntax, the wildcard variable will
>   contain the entire matching path segment, even if the document is
>   located in a deeply nested subcollection. For example, the rules
>   listed above would match a document located at
>   `/cities/SF/landmarks/coit_tower`, and the value of the document
>   variable would be `SF/landmarks/coit_tower`.

Note that you need to use the rules version 2.